# .NET Regex Lookbehind Not Greedy

Tags: .net, regex, lookbehind

How to get the lookbehind to be greedy?
In this case I want the lookbehind to consume the : if is is present.

```
m = Regex.Match("From: John", @"(?i)(?<=from:)....");
// returns ' Jon' what I expect not a problem just an example

m = Regex.Match("From: John", @"(?i)(?<=from:?)....");
// returns ': Jo'
// I want it to return ' Jon'
```

I found a work around

```
@"(?i)(?<=\bsubject:?\s+).*?(?=\s*\r?$)"
```

As long as you put some affirmative after the ? then it takes the optional greedy out of play.   For the same reason I had to put the $ in the look forward.
But if you need to end on an optional greedy then have to go with the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting, I didn't realise they were non-greedy in .NET. Here is one solution:

```
(?<=from(:|(?!:)))
```

This means:

```
(
  :     # match a ':'
  |
  (?!:) # otherwise match nothing (only if the next character isn't a ':')
)
```

This forces it to match the ':' if present.

Comment: Little verbose but it works and that works for me. Thanks.  I consider it a bug that the lookbehind is not greedy.

Comment: @Blam: Just realized this can be simplified to be less verbose. I updated my post.

Comment: No that fails the compiler please fix or go back to original answer rSubject = new Regex(@"(?i)(?<=subject(:|(?!:)))........)");

Comment: @Blam: There's a typo in your example - the last ')' shouldn't be there. `new Regex(@"(?i)(?<=subject(:|(?!:)))........")`

Comment: Thanks that seems to work.  I already gave you a +1 so I can't do it again.  Regex is cool but not very forgiving.